# Moving a toolbar button in XUL

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to get an element to move from right to left in XUL.  I am doing this with a toolbar and want one toolbarbutton w/ a label to remain anchored to the right, while one of them moves from right to left, starting to the left of the anchor.

I'm trying to achieve this effect by modifying marginLeft, but my element stays still.  I'm not really sure why it does not move.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE overlay >
<overlay id="my-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <script type="application/x-javascript">
    // Install load handler
    var marginLeft = 0;
    window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        function moveIt() {
       document.getElementById("moveit").style.marginLeft = marginLeft + "px";
       marginLeft -= 30;
    }
    setInterval(moveIt, 1000);
    }, false);
  </script>
  <vbox id="browser-bottombox">
    <toolbar id="theToolbar">
      <!-- holds the scrolling items and the refresh time -->
      <hbox id="scrollingItemContainer" flex="1" align="end">
        <!-- container for our scrolling items -->
        <spacer flex="1"/>        
        <hbox id="movingItems" align="end">
          <toolbarbutton id="moveit" label="moving"/>
        </hbox>
        <hbox>
          <toolbarbutton id="rightAnchor" label="right"/>
        </hbox>
      </hbox>   
    </toolbar>
  </vbox>
</overlay>
```

Any help you can provide will be helpful.  I've tried this on FF4, but I think the problem exists on FF3 as well.

I should note that if I add a spacer with flex=1 after scrollingItemContainer then I see the item move, but it is not anchored to the right.

Comment: I had all sorts of issues with xul, try putting flex on moveIt button. If that doesn't work try adding a spacer between two hboxes (movingItems and the next one) and then change this new spacer's width if possible.

Comment: Your item doesn't move because the spacer simply flexes to take up the "extra" space. Mihailo's idea of adding a new spacer and changing its width is the easiest way of achieving that particular animation, although there are others.